# Advanced Arc Routes

Tags: combinatorics

[image: arc_routes]

Sorry about the mess, basically I just cannot figure out a way to accurately estimate how many options there would be. Figuring out the number of options if you only use the top arcs or the bottom arcs is simple enough, but when trying to figure out how many possible ways there would be using the bottom and top arcs together becomes too tricky for me to solve, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

At any point, you have the option of advancing either by $1$ or by $2$. Thus you're looking for the number of ways to write $14$ as an ordered sum of $1$s and $2$s. This you can count either the pedestrian way: There can be $0$ to $7$ $2$s, and $k$ $2$s and $14-2k$ $1$s can be arranged in $\binom{14-k}k$ ways, so the total is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{14-k}k=610\;.
$$

Or you can note that $n$ can be written either by appending a $2$ to a sum for $n-2$ or by appending a $1$ to a sum for $n-1$, so $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$, where $a_n$ is the number of ways of writing $n$ as such a sum. This is the recurrence relation for the Fibonacci numbers, and with the initial conditions $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$ we obtain $a_n=F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. Indeed $F_{15}=610$.